# Why is the scope operator for std namespace not required in this case?

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I tried the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    all_of(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [](int i){return i;});
}
```

expecting a compilation error as I did not put `std::` in front of the `all_of` function, which is a part of the standard namespace. However contrary to my expectation, the code compiled. Why is `std::` not required in this case; does it have to do with using `myVector` in the `all_of` function?